# Cloud Bigtable HBase Client not functioning

Tags: bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

After following steps outlined in the below link, I can get the hbase shell launching however all those hbase commands throwing;ERROR: NPN/ALPN extensions not installed
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/installing-hbase-client

I have java version of  1.7.0_60-b19 and I used ALPN 7.1.0.v20141016

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What OS are you using?  Make sure you edit both the hbase-env.<sh,cmd> and hbase-site.xml and have your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS set correctly.

Comment: On my mac, I have
export HBASE_CLASSPATH="/Users/lesv/.m2/repository/com/google/cloud/bigtable/bigtable-hbase/0.1.9/bigtable-hbase-0.1.9.jar"

export HBASE_OPTS="${HBASE_OPTS} -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -Xbootclasspath/p:/Users/lesv/Bigtable-eap/hbase-1.0.0/lib/bigtable/alpn-boot-7.1.3.v20150130.jar "

Comment: On the documentation I don't see such instruction besides, I don't have alpn boot jar under that given home dir. That entry is expected to be in .bash_profile or hbase-env.sh?

Comment: hbase-env.sh for Mac/Linux, hbase-env.cmd for Windows  (its step 2 of https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/installing-hbase-client#editing_configuration_files )

Comment: Understood... I don't seem to find alpn-boot-*.jar in my local. Am i missing something?

Comment: Have you downloaded it ?  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty.alpn/alpn-boot  -- That is step 3 from https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/installing-hbase-client#downloading_required_files

Comment: On the doc, HBASE_CLASSPATH points to"$(pwd)/lib/bigtable/bigtable-hbase-0.1.5.jar" and in your comment above it is under mvn folder and new version thus I was searching alpn-boot file there. I found the issue with your help though. It is a copy past problem while downloading the jars. I truly appreciated your support

Comment: @East2West — Great to hear that you’ve solved your issue! Can you please move your solution into an answer and [accept it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the doc, HBASE_CLASSPATH points to"$(pwd)/lib/bigtable/bigtable-hbase-0.1.5.jar" and in your comment above it is under mvn folder and new version thus I was searching alpn-boot file there. I found the issue with your help though. It is a copy past problem while downloading the jars. I truly appreciated your support

Comment: FYI, 0.1.5 is now way out of date; the current version is 0.9.0.  We also got away from using alpn-boot in favor of the tcnative-boringssl jar which is much simpler to use.

Comment: i've posted this as it was requested to mark it answered:)